# How to rearrange items in the Unity 2D panel?

Tags: unity-2d

For performance reasons, I am currently using Unity 2D. I started Google Chrome and right-clicked the icon in the Unity panel and clicked "Keep in Launcher". However, I am not happy with the location in the panel that the icon ended up. I would like to move it around and re-arrange some other items as well.

I have tried dragging-and-dropping icons, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Launchpad Question #156866](https://answers.launchpad.net/unity-2d/+question/156866):

> You need to press and hold the left mouse button for 500ms on the icon you want to move. Then start moving the icon, it will follow the mouse cursor until you drop it, either by releasing the mouse button or by exiting the launcher's area.